How to visualize Similarity score matrix with CoNet app of Cytoscape
i got a similarity score matrix by using CCREPE package on R. I would like to visualize the co-occurence by using the app CoNet from Cytoscape. Everytime i upload the .TSV matrix and .TSV p-values, i got an error.
This is the similarity matrix:

This is the p-value matrix:

This is how i upload the tho files in CoNet:

This is the error i get once i tap "go":


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please show some of your input data. The first few lines of the .TSV matrix and .TSV p-values would be helpful.

thanks for your reply. I posted more pictures

My guess is that CoNet doesn't like NaN entries. Try changing those to 0 and see if it works.
